# Docker: error when running init and systemctl in shell script for CMD

Tags: docker, centos7

Dockerfile

```
# Use Centos7 or RHEL7 base image
FROM centos:7

# This steps are needed so that systemd works within container
#ENV container docker

RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl restart autofs
```

Now, I can run the following without a problem

```
docker build -t mycentos
docker run -d --privileged --name mycentos mycentos
docker exec -it  mycentos /bin/bash
./usr/local/bin/startup.sh
```

I would like that startup.sh to run automatically without me having to go into a container and run it manually

So, I just rolled /usr/sbin/init into startup.sh and changed Dockerfile CMD

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

and

startup.sh is now

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/init
systemctl restart autofs
```

I am getting the error

```
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how to get startup.sh to work?

PS I remember seeing the same error message when /usr/sbin/init was not running and i treid to run systemctl

EDIT
I've changed startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/systemctl restart autofs &
exec /usr/sbin/init
```

And it looks like autofs is never started from "docker run" CMD

```
$docker run --rm -itd --privileged --name mycentos mycentos
0c977e677897fc9a42bd3a4efe6742fbb14ed888a010cfee94c604436729db2d
$ docker exec -it mycentos /bin/bash
[root@0c977e677897 /]# systemctl status autofs
\u25cf autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on demand
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/autofs.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did not install autofs and the 2nd thing you did not enable it in docker file. you to enable it in Dockerfile first.

Here is your Dockerfile with a bit modification and the startup script as same as your updated one.

startup.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/systemctl restart autofs &
exec /usr/sbin/init
```

Dockerfile

```
 FROM centos:7

# This steps are needed so that systemd works within container
#ENV container docker

RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
RUN yum install -y autofs
COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
RUN systemctl enable autofs
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

*NOTE*: This also sometimes needs to mount cgroup for systemctl.

```
-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

Here run the command in a docker container

[image]

[image]

For further information, you can check this GitHub.

https://github.com/whyistheinternetbroken/docker-centos7-nfs-client-autofs/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: so why am i able to just run "systemctl restart autofs" insde of the container w/o calling systemctl enable autofs first?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/733469/what-is-the-difference-between-systemctl-start-and-systemctl-enable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: The systemctl status command provides not only information about whether the service / process is running (active), but also whether it is enabled to start at boot of the machine. This in itself would have required multiple programs (chkconfig etc) to query.

Comment: `/usr/bin/systemctl restart autofs &` just gives me the error `Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813588/systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container